# Confusion about Poisson process

Tags: python, statistics, poisson

My apologies if this is a very basic question, but I want to make sure I get this right. I have some time-series data which seem to fit the characteristics of a Poisson process. The data is from a simulation process where I can monitor events over time, and from that I can determine waiting times (i.e. the times between events).

The waiting times are stored in an array waittimes, and I calculate the average waiting time

```
    mean=numpy.mean(waittimes)
```

I then calculate an exponential with mean as the coefficient.

```
    samples = numpy.random.exponential(mean,size=10000)
```

Finally, I use the following code to calculate an "empirical" cumulative distribution function (ecdf)

```
def ecdf(data):
    # Number of data points: n                                                  
    n = len(data)

    # x-data for the ECDF: x                                                    
    x = numpy.sort(data)[::-1]                                                 

    # y-data for the ECDF: y                                                                                                 
    y = numpy.arange(1, n+1) / n

    return x,y
```

Determine the ECDF for both the empirical data and the exponential

```
    x,y=ecdf(waittimes)
    x_theor,y_theor=ecdf(samples)
```

Plotting (x,y) and (x_theor, y_theor) gives a reasonable agreement, indicating the waiting times are exponentially distributed.

Unfortunately my knowledge of the Poisson process is not what it should be. Somewhere in here I assume I should be able to calculate the Poisson rate parameter, and plot a poisson cdf similar to the ecdf above, but how to achieve this? Is the mean of the waiting times the same as the rate in the Poisson process, or something like rate=1/mean or something different?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `lambda` in a Poisson distribution is the expected number of events and is dimensionless --- it is not a rate, which would have dimensions inverse time.

If the number of events in windows of size `T` follows a Poisson distribution with parameter `lambda` (no dimension), then the wait times between events should follow an exponential distribution with mean `T/lambda` (time).